# How can I obtain focused blinking I-beam cursor coordinate on the screen reliably?

Tags: x11, mouse

Is it to possible retrieve x,y coordinates of [I-beam cursor](https://www.computerhope.com/jargon/i/ibeam.htm) reliably?
For example while editing text or entering some commands into the shell, mouse position and I-beam cursor can be at different coordinates.
While it's very easy to get mouse position on the screen, I haven't come across any documentaion regarding how to obtain position of I-beam cursor on the screen.

**EDIT:** I want to obtain position of focused , which is blinking, one of the I-beams.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean when the mouse cursor has an “I-beam” shape, that's just the mouse cursor position. If you mean the place in a text fragment where the text will be edited, then no, because the concept you're looking for doesn't exist.

The concept of text cursor position is entirely application-specific. The operating system keeps track of where the mouse cursor is and draws it on the screen, but it's up to each application to display text cursors where it wants.

An application can have multiple text cursors (for example one in each sub-window or pane or text box, or following different parts of text that change in parallel), or none at all. They typically don't have a well-defined screen position: their intent is to indicate a position in text, and they may either be located on screen between characters or over a character.

If you have a specific problem to solve in a specific application (or in a group of applications that use the same GUI widget library), there may be a solution for that.

Comment: "The operating system keeps track of where the mouse cursor is and draws it on the screen." Isn't that the X server?

Comment: @Quasímodo Yes (or an alternative like Wayland or Quartz).